# Function type signatures

Tags: ocaml, signature

I tried to find this somewhere in internet, but I failed to do this. I want to learn OCaml and that's difficult to understand for me, how to do this.

My question is - how can I easy write a function, when I have a signature. For example - I have a signature like this:

```
((int -> int) -> int -> int -> int) -> (int -> int) -> int -> int -> int
```

and I want to write a function, that have signature like this above. Would someone help me or try to explain this? I would be very grateful :)

Answer (score 5):

A function with type `'a -> 'b`, takes values of some type `'a` and returns values of some type `'b`. To use specific types, a function of type `int -> int` takes an int and returns an int. This is the type of integer negation, for example.

One way to look at a function with type `'a -> 'b -> 'c` is that it takes two values, of type `'a` and `'b`, and returns a value of type `'c`. A specific example would be the type `int -> int -> int`, which is the type of integer addition (say):

```
# (+);;
- : int -> int -> int = <fun>
```

This pattern continues for more arguments.

The type you give has this type at the high level: `'a -> 'b -> 'c -> 'd -> 'e`. So, it's a function with four arguments.

The first argument has type `(int -> int) -> int -> int -> int`, which is itself quite complicated. The second argument has type `int -> int`, described above. The third and fourth arguments have type `int`. The function returns an `int`.

Using this same analysis on the first argument, you can see that it's a function with three arguments. The first is a function of type `int -> int`, and the second and third are of type `int`. This function returns an `int`.

Here's a function of type `(int -> int) -> int -> int -> int`:

```
let myfun f a b =
    (f a) + a + b
```

You can see the type in the OCaml toplevel:

```
# let myfun f a b =
     (f a) + a + b;;
val myfun : (int -> int) -> int -> int -> int = <fun>
#
```

You should be able to work out the rest. I don't want to take all the enjoyment out of the problem by giving a full answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I do not know if I understand correctly, the whole function with this long signature, it will be in the "myfun" only? I must declare new variables or something? Sorry, it may be stupid question, but I tried some actions and there's only val myfun : (int -> int) -> int -> int -> int -> int -> int

Comment: You need to declare a function something like this: `let myfun2 g h a b = ...`. Inside this function you need to call `g` using arguments like those accepted by `myfun` above, and you need to call `h` using arguments like those accepted by `f` above. The compiler determines the types of things by seeing how you use them in the code. So you have to use them in the proper way to get the right type.

Comment: Oh, I did this! Thanks a lot! I can't upvote You right now, but I'll do this, when I can :)